# How to break email address text into a table cell by specific charactes like '@' or '.'?

Tags: html, css, line-breaks, tabular

I have a table. One column of this table is a email address. The email is a string without spaces.

When there's no enough space I need to break this text into multiple lines in function of '@' and '.' charactes.

Given the following email strings:

```
john@email.com
richard.developer@email.com
```

This is what I expect:

```
john@email.com
richard
.developer
@email.com
```

This is what I not expect:

```
john@email.com
richard.
developer
@email.com
```

How could I achieve this using CSS and HTML?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved!

Two methods:

**Method 1 (Not works in IE)**

```
<td>
      richard<wbr>.<wbr>developer<wbr>@<wbr>gmail<wbr>.<wbr>com
</td>
```

Thanks to n_ermosh in:
[Specifying a preferred line break point in HTML text in a responsive design](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18222409/specifying-a-preferred-line-break-point-in-html-text-in-a-responsive-design)

**Method 2**

CSS:

```
.break {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

HTML:

```
<td>
   <span class="break">richard</span>
   <span class="break">.</span>
   <span class="break">developer</span>
   <span class="break">@</span>
   <span class="break">developer</span>
   <span class="break">.</span>
   <span class="break">com</span>
</td>
```

Thanks to jomo in:
[Specifying a preferred line break point in HTML text in a responsive design](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18222409/specifying-a-preferred-line-break-point-in-html-text-in-a-responsive-design)

Answer (score 1):

Can I suggest you to achieve other effect? Have three dots when text is longer than container?

```css
td span{
  display:block;
  width: 100px;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td><span>very.long.email@google.com</span></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Thanks for reply.  This is not exactly what I need in this case, altough would be useful to me in other situation. Unfortunately its not working. Also Its a situation where the column size is not defined. Only the other two columns have specific size.