# Optionally wrapping text

Tags: html, css

I got some slogans that can either be displayed on a single line or multiple lines if wrapped at specific places. Is there a CSS option to respect a <br> tag only if necessary to fit the container width and leave it unwrapped otherwise?

For example

```html
<div>
  They told me that<br> aesthetics matter.
</div>
```

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/overflow-wrap

Comment: This question has been asked many times before (e.g., <https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18222409/specifying-a-preferred-line-break-point-in-html-text-in-a-responsive-design>).  Please search before posting.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Specifying a preferred line break point in HTML text in a responsive design](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18222409/specifying-a-preferred-line-break-point-in-html-text-in-a-responsive-design)

Comment: @user81993 Hey, hopping in real quick to check whether I solved your issue or do I need to ameliorate my skills?

Answer (score 0):

You can use CSS code to break work

```css
#content::after {
  content: "\a";
  white-space: pre;
}
```

```html
<div id="content">They told me that</div>
<div id="break">aesthetics matter.</div>
```

and also you can define `padding` instead of `height` because `padding` expands the container according to its children and also prevent children to overflow the example is the following

```css
#container {
  width: 300px;
  padding: 5px;
  background-color: grey;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor
  in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can CSS property `word-wrap: break-word;` in `div` to solve your issue. And if it doesn't solve your issue, let me know in comments I will try my best to help you.