# Capitalize first letter only if it's not on the first line?

Tags: html, css

I'm breaking up a long string using the method here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/24357132

```css
.line {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<p>
  <span class="line">This text should break</span>
  <span class="line">after the word "break"</span>
</p>
```

However, if the line break appears, I'd like to capitalize the first letter of the second line. So if the line break doesn't appear, it'll say:

```
This text should break after the word "break"
```

If the line break appears, it should say:

```
This text should break
After the word "break"
```

I tried the following, but none of them work:

```
.line:not(::first-line)::first-letter {
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

```
.line::first-letter {
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.line::first-line {
  text-transform: none !important;
}
```

```
.line::first-letter {
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.line::first-line::first-character {
  text-transform: none !important;
}
```

Is this possible without JS?

Comment: Why is JS not an option? Or just curious, if it is possible with CSS?

Comment: Looking at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5577380/9038475), it seems , that `::first-character` should be `::first-letter`.

Comment: Typo in the question, "first-letter" didn't work either

Comment: It works fine in jsfiddle with `.line::first-letter {text-transform: uppercase;}`. Do you have other CSS, which you use on the line class or span elements, which might have an influence on it? For example, is there something, which might change the display to something not block related?

Answer (score 0):

> Is this possible without JS?

Only with difficulty, and by manually tuning your CSS rules to the specific content. CSS is not really row oriented. You're looking for a selector that can target the first element in each row, on which you can apply `::first-letter`, but there's nothing in CSS which can do that. Probably the closest thing would `::first-line`, but since that and `::first-letter` are both pseudo-elements they can't be used together. If you're fine with each of your `span` elements being exactly the same width you could do it with CSS grid, but that would cause whitespace gaps between the `span`s when they're fitted to the grid, breaking up the text flow, so I doubt that's the solution you're looking for.

For a CSS-only solution you're unfortunately limited to finding every screen size at which a new wrap occurs, and writing a media query that uses `nth-child` to target the specific elements that are at the beginning of each line.

```css
.line {
  display: inline-block;
}
@media (max-width: 792px) {
  .line:nth-child(1)::first-letter { text-transform: uppercase; }
  .line:nth-child(2)::first-letter { text-transform: none; }
  .line:nth-child(3)::first-letter { text-transform: none; }
  .line:nth-child(4)::first-letter { text-transform: none; }
  .line:nth-child(5)::first-letter { text-transform: none; }
  .line:nth-child(6)::first-letter { text-transform: uppercase; }
}
@media (max-width: 698px) {
  .line:nth-child(1)::first-letter { text-transform: uppercase; }
  .line:nth-child(2)::first-letter { text-transform: none; }
  .line:nth-child(3)::first-letter { text-transform: none; }
  .line:nth-child(4)::first-letter { text-transform: none; }
  .line:nth-child(5)::first-letter { text-transform: uppercase; }
  .line:nth-child(6)::first-letter { text-transform: none; }
}
@media (max-width: 502px) {
  .line:nth-child(1)::first-letter { text-transform: uppercase; }
  .line:nth-child(2)::first-letter { text-transform: none; }
  .line:nth-child(3)::first-letter { text-transform: none; }
  .line:nth-child(4)::first-letter { text-transform: uppercase; }
  .line:nth-child(5)::first-letter { text-transform: none; }
  .line:nth-child(6)::first-letter { text-transform: none; }
}
@media (max-width: 441px) {
  .line:nth-child(1)::first-letter { text-transform: uppercase; }
  .line:nth-child(2)::first-letter { text-transform: none; }
  .line:nth-child(3)::first-letter { text-transform: none; }
  .line:nth-child(4)::first-letter { text-transform: uppercase; }
  .line:nth-child(5)::first-letter { text-transform: none; }
  .line:nth-child(6)::first-letter { text-transform: uppercase; }
}
@media (max-width: 368px) {
  .line:nth-child(1)::first-letter { text-transform: uppercase; }
  .line:nth-child(2)::first-letter { text-transform: none; }
  .line:nth-child(3)::first-letter { text-transform: uppercase; }
  .line:nth-child(4)::first-letter { text-transform: none; }
  .line:nth-child(5)::first-letter { text-transform: uppercase; }
  .line:nth-child(6)::first-letter { text-transform: none; }
}
@media (max-width: 313px) {
  .line:nth-child(1)::first-letter { text-transform: uppercase; }
  .line:nth-child(2)::first-letter { text-transform: none; }
  .line:nth-child(3)::first-letter { text-transform: uppercase; }
  .line:nth-child(4)::first-letter { text-transform: none; }
  .line:nth-child(5)::first-letter { text-transform: uppercase; }
  .line:nth-child(6)::first-letter { text-transform: uppercase; }
}
@media (max-width: 310px) {
  .line:nth-child(1)::first-letter { text-transform: uppercase; }
  .line:nth-child(2)::first-letter { text-transform: uppercase; }
  .line:nth-child(3)::first-letter { text-transform: none; }
  .line:nth-child(4)::first-letter { text-transform: uppercase; }
  .line:nth-child(5)::first-letter { text-transform: uppercase; }
  .line:nth-child(6)::first-letter { text-transform: uppercase; }
}
@media (max-width: 226px) {
  .line:nth-child(1)::first-letter { text-transform: uppercase; }
  .line:nth-child(2)::first-letter { text-transform: uppercase; }
  .line:nth-child(3)::first-letter { text-transform: uppercase; }
  .line:nth-child(4)::first-letter { text-transform: none; }
  .line:nth-child(5)::first-letter { text-transform: uppercase; }
  .line:nth-child(6)::first-letter { text-transform: uppercase; }
}
@media (max-width: 207px) {
  .line:nth-child(1)::first-letter { text-transform: uppercase; }
  .line:nth-child(2)::first-letter { text-transform: uppercase; }
  .line:nth-child(3)::first-letter { text-transform: uppercase; }
  .line:nth-child(4)::first-letter { text-transform: uppercase; }
  .line:nth-child(5)::first-letter { text-transform: uppercase; }
  .line:nth-child(6)::first-letter { text-transform: uppercase; }
}
```

```html
<p>
  <span class="line">This text should break</span>
  <span class="line">after the word "break".</span>
  <span class="line">and then</span>
  <span class="line">we have some more</span>
  <span class="line">text to demonstrate spans with</span>
  <span class="line">varying length</span>
</p>
```

The above code could be optimised somewhat, but goes to show how arduous this is to set up in pure CSS. And, of course, if the text content changes at all you'll need to recompute all the breakpoints.

---

If you are open to using JavaScript then a simple function can compute whether each `span` is wrapped to the far left of its parent, and if so have a class added that applies `text-transform: uppercase` to the first letter.

```js
const setCapitals = () => {
  const spans = document.querySelectorAll( '.wrap-capitals span' )
  spans.forEach( span => {
    span.classList.toggle( 'upper', span.offsetLeft === 0 )
  } )
}

window.addEventListener( 'resize', setCapitals )
window.addEventListener( 'load', setCapitals )
```

```css
.wrap-capitals {
  position: relative;
}
.wrap-capitals > span {
  display: inline-block;
}
.wrap-capitals > span.upper::first-letter {
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

```html
<p class="wrap-capitals">
  <span>This text should break</span>
  <span>after the word "break".</span>
  <span>and then</span>
  <span>we have some more</span>
  <span>text to demonstrate spans with</span>
  <span>varying length</span>
</p>
```

Comment: even the js solution seems to fail if you make the width below 300px I guess

Answer (score 0):

Since `::first-letter` does not work on inline elements such as a span. Using `::first-letter` will not affect your style since it only works on block elements such as a paragraph(`<p>`), or those with their display property set to inline-block.

By doing so, you need to set your span first and display it as `block` using -> `span {display:block;}` then make your `selector`.

```css
span {display:block;}
p span.line:not(:first-of-type)::first-letter {
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

```html
<p>
  <span class="line">This text should break</span>
  <span class="line">after the word "break"</span>
</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you read the specs on the [`::first-line`](https://drafts.csswg.org/selectors-3/#first-line) and [`::first-letter`](https://drafts.csswg.org/selectors-3/#first-letter) you'll see that what your looking for is impossible.

They way that these work, is that the CSSDom creates "fictional tags" like the following:

```
// Example
p { color: red; font-size: 12pt }
p::first-letter { color: green; font-size: 200% }
p::first-line { color: blue }

<P>Some text that ends up on two lines</P>

// CSSDom output
<P>
<P::first-line>
<P::first-letter>
S
</P::first-letter>ome text that
</P::first-line>
ends up on two lines
</P>
```

The CSSDom can't figure out where to put these "fictional tags" when you use `inline` elements.   You need to have a single block element for these "fictional tags" to even work.

That said, even if you DID have a single block element, you still wouldn't be able to select the second line's `::first-letter` because that fictional tag is wrapped inside the `::first-line`, and there isn't support for `::second-line` or anything beyond the first.

#### So, if you want to do this without JS

You're going to have to get creative, and write a lot of Media queries, and do a lot of quality assurance to make sure that your type fits nicely inside what you're trying to create.

Based on what you've shared, here's a relatively flexible, and simple version of how I'd handle these requirements.

```css
/* 1 item on mobile */
@media (max-width: 599px) {
  .line-container {
    width: 20ch;
  }

  .line-container .line {
    display: inline-block;
  }

  .line-container .line:first-letter {
    text-transform: uppercase;
  }
}

/* 2 items on Tablet */
@media (min-width: 600px) and (max-width: 1023px) {
  .line-container {
    width: calc(20ch * 2);
  }

  .line-container .line {
    display: inline-block;
  }

  .line-container .line:nth-child(2n + 3):first-letter {
    text-transform: uppercase;
  }
}

/* 3 items on Desktop */
@media (min-width: 1024px) {
  .line-container {
    width: calc(20ch * 3);
  }

  .line-container .line {
    display: inline-block;
  }

  .line-container .line:nth-child(3n + 4):first-letter {
    text-transform: uppercase;
  }
}
```

```html
<p class="line-container">
  <span class="line">This text should break</span>
  <span class="line">after the word "break"</span>
  <span class="line">after the word "break"</span>
  <span class="line">after the word "break"</span>
  <span class="line">after the word "break"</span>
  <span class="line">after the word "break"</span>
  <span class="line">after the word "break"</span>
</p>
```

Comment: I would like to use CSS var's inside here, but they don't work inside `:nth-child()` selectors unfortunately.

Answer (score -1):

Use this one for capitalize first letter:

```
.line::first-letter { text-transform: uppercase; }
```